# Is it possible to add an OnClick Intent to one of these markers?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I want to add an onClick to each one of these markers so I cant open a new activity for each one of them, is that possible an array of markers?

For some reason it will not let me post my code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help without any code to see what you are doing but ...

The way this works is you have a a GoogleMap object so something like this

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

you then call

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(someObject);
```

where someObject is an instance of a class that implements OnMarkerClickListener, which means it has a method like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // identify the marker you want and then do what ever you think should be done
    // for example when you added the marker, you could have given it a unique title
    // which you can check of here using
    if (marker.getTitle.equals("blah") {
       // do something
    } else {
       // do something else
    }
    return true;
}
```